# Localização do arquivo em que os dados são salvos na biblioteca Parse

Tags: java, android, parse

Estou fazendo a manutenção de um projeto android que foi desenvolvido usando a biblioteca parse para fazer a camada de persistência. 
http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/

Não encontrei na API, onde o arquivo usado para gravar as informações fica localizado. Alguém já trabalhou com essa biblioteca, sabe onde o arquivo fica salvo?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Bruno, viajei, coloquei o comentário na pergunta errada! Acho que eu estava meio dormindo, ou aconteceu algum bug aqui.